# Issues installing Apache airflow

Tags: python

I'm on MacOS Mojave, Python 3.8.3, and pip 23.2.
I made a py_env, activated it, and ran

```
pip install apache-airflow==2.6.3' \
 --constraint "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/apache/airflow/constraints-2.6.3/constraints-3.8.txt".
```

At first I had an error saying it couldn't find file "pybind11". I installed pybind11 by running python -m pip install pybind11, but now theres multiple unknown type errors and other errors.

```
python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [140 lines of output]
running bdist_wheel
running build
running build_py
creating build
creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-38
copying re2.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-38
running build_ext
building '_re2' extension
creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-38
gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -
DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -
I/Users/chu/opt/anaconda3/include -arch x86_64 -
I/Users/chu/opt/anaconda3/include -arch x86_64 -
I/Users/chu/Desktop/Airflow_test/py_env/lib/python3.8/site-
packages/pybind11/include -
I/Users/chu/Desktop/Airflow_test/py_env/include -
I/Users/chu/opt/anaconda3/include/python3.8 -c _re2.cc -o
build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-38/_re2.o -fvisibility=hidden
In file included from _re2.cc:11:
...
/Users/chu/Desktop/Airflow_test/py_env/lib/python3.8/site-
packages/pybind11/include/pybind11/detail/common.h:688:18: warning: 
alias declarations are a C++11 extension [-Wc++11-extensions]
using type = ISeq;
^
fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-
limit=]
18 warnings and 20 errors generated.
error: command '/usr/bin/gcc' failed with exit code 1
[end of output]
note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a 
problem with pip.
ERROR: Failed building wheel for google-re2
Running setup.py clean for google-re2
Failed to build google-re2
ERROR: Could not build wheels for google-re2, which is required to 
install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

Comment: Why do you have `apache-http-server` tagged? Apache Airflow is a different product. Using the wrong tags can get your question downvoted or closed. However, your problem is a Python problem building and installing a package (c/c++ compile issue).

Comment: Building on macOS is known to work, but has been known to fail.
    For example, the system Python may not know which compiler flags
    to set when building bindings for software installed by Homebrew;
    see https://docs.brew.sh/Homebrew-and-Python#brewed-python-modules. Quote from [reference](https://pypi.org/project/google-re2/)

Answer (score 1):

I would start with the bottom most error and go from there..

`ERROR: Could not build wheels for google-re2, which is required to  install pyproject.toml-based projects`

Seems like google-re2 is a constraint that needs to be met.

Start with `pip install google-re2` https://pypi.org/project/google-re2/

You can also head to https://raw.githubusercontent.com/apache/airflow/constraints-2.6.3/constraints-3.8.txt which is the list of required packages that need to be available for airflow installation to be successful.

You can compare this with the list of packages already installed. You can do so by running `pip list` or `pip list -v` (verbose - give you the location of the packages installed)